# Rails 4 - Meta tags html safe

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, meta-tags, html-safe

I am trying to figure out the best way to make my meta tags html safe. They are currently escaping out any html.

Here is my current setup.

in my application.html.erb:

```
<meta name="description" content="<%= yield(:description) %>">
```

and in my views:

```
<% provide(:description, "Things being escaped from here") %>
```

if I simply call html safe on the `provide` like so...

```
<% provide(:description, "now it's html safe".html_safe) %>
```

it works fine, but I am wondering if there is a better practice in doing this. I find it wrong to have to call html safe on every single view where I am using the `provide` method.

Comment: I would rather patch the provide method. Is that from Rails API, or a gem, or something you built yourself?

Comment: The provide method comes with Rails. What exactly do you mean by patch @Meeh

Comment: what about `metamagic` gem?  https://github.com/lassebunk/metamagic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom helper based on the [original provide](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/CaptureHelper.html#method-i-provide).

```
# app/helpers/application_helper.rb
module ApplicationHelper
  def provide_safe(name, content)
    provide(name, content.html_safe)
  end
end
```

And in your views, just replace `provide` by `provide_safe`

```
<% provide_safe(:description, "now it's html safe") %>
```